# Проблема с date picker mui react

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, mui

у меня есть такой date picker

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => {

    return (
      <>
        <InfoAlert dateInfo={dateInfo} type="warning" />
        <LocalizationProvider
          dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
          adapterLocale={ru}
        >
          <DatePickerStyled
            format="dd.MM.yyyy"
            value={value}
            inputRef={ref}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            minDate={minDate}
            label={label}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </>
    );
  }}
```

поле это обязательное, если очистить значения в нем, то сработает триггер, что поле обязательное и я об этом узнаю, но если удалить руками только год, а все остальное оставить и уйти с инпута, то инпут становится пустым, серым как будто там ничего нет, если кликнуть снова на него, то видно что там лежит дата (день и месяц) а года нет, при этом поле считается заполненным, напомню что оно обязательное, если оно не заполнено, то я об этом вижу, а тут получается оно заполненоо только день и месяц и типа норм, считается заполненным, шо за бред?! и самое главное когда я консолю value мне показывается вся дата, вместе с годом вот  Wed Mar 20 2024 18:25:59 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time)
Как бы так сделать, чтобы я либо видел, что у меня дата кривая и кастомно выдавал ошибку, либо чтобы это матириаловское поле нормально проверяло значение, а то понапишут всякого, поле заполнено не верно, а все норм все работаеть(

Comment: не очень понятно что за датапикер используется, но обычно - это инпут с запретом редактирования, по клику на который появляется календарь с выбором даты. Т.е.  руками вводить/изменять ничего не нужно - автоматически появляется после выбора из календаря. Если у вас не так - то добавить readonly input